# doctrine - How to set orderBy clause wtih column name (not entity field)?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

i have a product entity that extends from base entity. product entity doesn't have a "created_at" field (attribute - variable) but base entity has, so product table in MySQL has a column named created_at (because it extends from base entity class). in doctrine orm, query builder mapped from product entity and doesn't recognize "created_at" field. i want to get products ordered by "created_at" but it gives me an error that the field "created_at" is not defined in product entity. is there any solution to set orderBy function based on column name and not on entity?

my function:

```
$queryBuilder->addOrderBy('product.created_at', 'ASC');
```

error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 86 near 'created_at A': Error: Class App\\Entity\\Product has no field or association named created_at
```

product table schema:

[image]

Comment: Does it work with `$queryBuilder->addOrderBy('product.createdAt', 'ASC');` ?

Comment: @DylanKAS yes, thank you, i just found my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i found my mistake. change clause to :

```
$queryBuilder->addOrderBy('product.createdAt', 'ASC');
```

column's name is created_at but the field is createdAt (strange!!!)
by the way here is my product entity and base entity (just for better understanding):
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's not strange at all; as per Symfony conventions (a somewhat modified PSR-12) class properties are named in `camelCase` and the default doctrine naming strategy is the [`UnderscoreNamingStrategy`](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/2.13.x/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/UnderscoreNamingStrategy.php) , that converts the `camelCase` property name to an `snake_case` column name.